# Redirect to custom error page if there is error in the page

Tags: php, jsp, custom-error-pages

I am new to `PHP` web development. I want to know is there any code in PHP that redirects me to a page(*let's name it "myerrorpage.php"*) if there is some error on the page?

In `JSP` it's possible using the following code

```
<%@ page errorPage="myerrorpage.jsp" %>
```

I want to know is there any above `JSP` type of code in PHP?is yes then please help

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In php you don't redirect when there is an error in the code, you simply catch that error and then you take whatever actions you consider necessary.

In order to catch the errors in the code, you must define a custom error handler, using [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Also you can handle the uncaught exceptions using [set_exception_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

The following code will redirect to `yourerrorpage.php` when there is an error on the PHP code.

```
<?php
function error_found(){
  header("Location: yourerrorpage.php");
}
set_error_handler('error_found');
?>
```

Please note that the `header("Location: page.php");` redirect type doesn't work after the content output begins.

---

Alternatively, you might want to try [Apache custom error responses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle error in php using .htaccess.Create .htaccess file in root of website and add following into file

ErrorDocument 400 /400.html

ErrorDocument 401 /401.html

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

ErrorDocument 502 /502.html

ErrorDocument 504 /504.html

Now create all pages 400.html,401.html etc pages into root of your website.When error occurred user will redirect to the pages.

Thanks

Comment: its also a good one but i got my ans which is a `PHP` code.. thanks for contribution +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always send a new header with the new location like:

```
header('Location: myerrorpage.php');
```

Just make sure you don't output anything before calling the header() because then it will not work.
Then you ofcourse just need to check if an error occured and then call the header() appropriately.

Comment: this code just redirect me to some page.but how someone can check is there any error in the page?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple..
You just need to enable by configuring **httpd.conf** file which is located in **xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf**

1. Search for **<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">**.
2. Under the section, look for **#AllowOverride All**
3. Just Remove the '#' which means comment and you're ready for the further step.

The next thing you need to do is create a file named '**.htaccess**' on you root directory.

1. Make sure it is just **.htaccess**
2. Edit using your favorite text editor(Sublime, Atom, Notepad++, etc)
3. Write the code....

.

```
ErrorDocument 404 YourDirectory/error page
```

eg.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/project/error.php
```