# HTML Redirect on visit

Tags: html, redirect

I'm making a website in HTML and I'm wondering how I can redirect users to the down for maintenance page when my page is down. I don't want to change the whole index.html to the maintenance page because that would be annoying to do. Can anyone help with this?

Note: I am using Apache.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970667/redirect-to-custom-error-page-if-there-is-error-in-the-page

Comment: Why is the site going to be down if you are just using plain HTML? Down for maintenance a thing systems do when they are, for example, upgrading huge databases.

Comment: Depends on whether you want server-side redirection or client-side redirection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For pure HTML, all you need to know about is the `<meta>` tag. Specifically, a meta refresh. In HTML5, you can add this to your document's head:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;someOtherPage.html">`

The 0 is the number of seconds to wait until it redirects (0=instantly on page load), the `someOtherPage.html` is obviously the URL to the new page. You can leave out the URL and semicolon to just refresh the current page (using non-zero values for the delay), but that's not relevant to this specific topic.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is now working how I want it. =)